# How can I post with an instance variable and HTTParty to an API that uses OAuth2

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, httparty

I can get information from an Oauth2 API by:

```
token = "Token I get from authenticating my App"
auth = "Bearer " + token
user = HTTParty.get("API Website", :headers => { "Authorization" => auth})
```

How would I post to that API content generated in my app? I have an instance variable:

```
@contact = {"contact": {"name": "John Doe"  }}
```

I tried this:

```
token = "Token I get from authenticating my App"
auth = "Bearer " + token
user = HTTParty.get("API Website", :headers => { "Authorization" => auth}, @contact)
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answered my own question

```
HTTParty.post("API Website", :headers => { "Authorization" => auth}, :body => "@contact")
```

Comment: Was the problem that you needed to `post` instead of `get`, or that you needed to add the key `:body` to the post request?

Comment: I believe it was the body key. nowadays though I use and strongly recommend the Net::HTTP library that's in the ruby standard lib, http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post because I have come to realize that the less dependencies I have in an app the better.